# News events around the world

Tags: api, global

Is there a website/ API that can tell you the number of news articles that talks about a specific country? For example the number of news sources about Brazil ought to be extremely high (Olympics) right now.

It would be great if there was a read count on it as well (like reddits up and down voting of news), but I can do without it.

Answer (score 2):

Gdelt is the one you need and want.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to bring it up to SE quality? *Why* will that site help the OP? Where is the link? Thanks. (The way it is written now it could be spam)